# Normal artifact or something else?

Tags: disassembly, x86, elf, intel

I'm working on a Linux ELF challenge.

I have found this bit of code in the `.text` disassembly using `objdump -d -M intel program`

```
 922:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 925:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
 92c:   83 7d f4 00             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
 930:   74 29                   je     95b <main@@Base+0x26b>   
 
 932:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
 935:   ff 75 f4                push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
 938:   8d 83 e4 ea ff ff       lea    eax,[ebx-0x151c]
 93e:   50                      push   eax
 93f:   e8 ac fb ff ff          call   4f0 <printf@plt>
 944:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 947:   8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
 94a:   0f af 45 f4             imul   eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
 94e:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],eax
 951:   8b 55 08                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 954:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
 957:   01 d0                   add    eax,edx
 959:   ff d0                   call   eax
```

There are no references to address `932` in the code so it is either an indirect call like we see at the last address `959` or it is intentionally left out and I have to patch to get to this section.  I suspect it is the latter as there is a piece of code elsewhere that points to a `deadc0de` address.  However, When I patch to this section, the only string given is `"Unexpected error condition. Control char is %d\n"` which makes me wonder if this is some sort of normal compiler artifact.

My questions are

1. Am I focusing on the wrong section because this ***is*** indeed a normal artifact?
2. If `925` sets a stack address to `0` and then `92c` compares that same stack address to `0`, is there any way that this check could ever fail so that `je` at `930` is not taken?

**27-04-2022 EDIT:**
`readelf -x .rodata <program>` returns the "Unexpected error condition ..." string as part of the rodata section.  This very much leads me to believe that this is not a compiler artifact and is instead, part of the challenge

Comment: Why do you think `932` be called? I see that `92c` could be part of a loop. The stack operation is only at `932 ` to make the `printf` call. Can you share the original binary?

Comment: @sudhackar  I cannot share the binary.  It is not an open crackme but rather a challenge as part of a CTF that prohibits placing challenge information into public space.  That is why I have shared so little of the code here.  `92c` is not part of a loop.  '922' - `930` marks the end of a conditional branch that gets taken if the program is supplied a proper password.  The line above [not shown here] is a call to print the "correct password" string.